# Mongoose populate within an object?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm not sure how to populate the sample schema below or if it is even possible.  Can a reference be within an object like below?  If you can, how would you populate it?  E.g. `.populate('map_data.location');`?

```
var sampleSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  map_data: [{
    location: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'location'},
    count: Number
  }]
});
```

Or will I have to have two separate arrays for location and count like so:

```
// Locations and counts should act as one object. They should
// Be synced together perfectly.  E.g. locations[i] correlates to counts[i]
locations: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'location'}],
counts: [Number]
```

I feel like the first solution would be the best, but I'm not entirely sure how to get it working within Mongoose.

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The first solution is possible.

Mongoose currently has limitations ([see this ticket here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/601)) populating multiple levels of embedded documents, however *is* very good at understanding nested paths within a single document - what you're after in this case.

Example syntax would be:

`YourSchema.find().populate('map_data.location').exec(...)`

Other features, such as specifying getters / setters on paths, orderBy and where clauses, etc. also accept a nested paths, like this example from the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html):

```
personSchema.virtual('name.full').get(function () {
  return this.name.first + ' ' + this.name.last;
});
```

Internally Mongoose splits the string at the dots and sorts everything out for you.

Comment: As far as the second point goes: Do you have a top element?  If so, give everything a top_id and a parent_id.  Or  descendents array and a children array.  Then, take everything from top, and sort out inheritance on client side.

Answer (score 18):

First option is ok, but if someone would have problems with that query `map_data.location` - Mongoose returns empty array instead of object - I found that this will work:

```
.populate({
     path: 'map_data.location',
     model: 'Location'
})
```

Comment: According to the [**documentation**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#cross-db-populate), it seems that specifying the `model` key is only useful if you need to populate across MongoDB databases or MongoDB instances.

Answer (score 4):

```js
   YourSchema.find()
       .populate({
            path: 'map_data',
            populate: {
                path: 'location' 
            }
    }).exec(...)
```

The above statement will populate array of map_data and also the location object of each map_data.

hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

i think you will need this:

if you schema is this:

```
var sampleSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
map_data: [{
location: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'location'},
count: Number
}]
});
```

you monggosse query have to be:

```
const responseMap=await YourSchema.find()
.populate(
path: 'map_data._id',
model: 'location'
select:['nameLocation','geoPoints','count'],
).exec();
console.log(responseMap);
```

but you **count** variable have to be in **location schema**, and map_data have to containt only id location.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We usually don't recommend sending regards, thanks, or any other tagline in order to keep the content of the answer clear & concise and to adhere to the technical writing guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

If someone couldn't solve his/her problem I got a solution It works for me.

My Schema:

```
const categorySchema = new Schema(
{
    name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    products: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Product'
    }]
})
```

And then to get a category with an specific name and with their products:

```
.get('/:name', async (req, res) => {
const { name } = req.params;
    
    const responseMap = await Category.find({name})
            .populate({
                path: 'products',
                model: 'Product',
            })
            .exec();

    res.send(responseMap);})
```

Answer (score 0):

The first option is the best. "count" is part of object "map_data".