# Mongoose populate with array of objects containing ref

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have a Mongoose schema with an array `lists` of objects that consist of a reference to another collection and a nested array of numbers:

```js
var Schema, exports, mongoose, schema;
    
mongoose = require("mongoose");
    
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    
schema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true
    },
    lists: [{
        list: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            require: true,
            ref: "List"
        },
        allocations: [{
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }]
    }],
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        "default": Date.now
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: Date
    }
});
    
exports = module.exports = mongoose.model("Portfolio", schema);
```

However, I cannot get `populate` to work as expected without getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined`. I've tried `populate('list')` and `populate('lists list')` but I'm either not calling things correctly or my Schema isn't formed correctly. I don't have this problem if I simply reference the lists by themselves:

```js
lists: [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    require: true,
    ref: "List"
}]
```

but I want to have the allocations array alongside each list. What do I need to do to get the behavior I want?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

I found the answer: `populate('lists.list')` works. Thanks to this question: [Mongoose populate within an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594511/mongoose-populate-within-an-object?rq=1)

Comment: Hi friend this is not working for me any thing i miss. i havent use required.

Comment: it worked for me. i was populating for each service inside services array thanks.
`services:[{
       quantity: Number,
       service: {
           type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
           ref: 'vas'
       }
    }],`

Answer (score 9):

**Actual answer:**

Use this,

```
populate('lists.list')
```

**Extra:**

Here are lists are an array of objects (list).
In JS you can access this like that,

```
console.log(lists.list);
```

and MongoDB syntax is 99% similar to JS syntax.
so....................

Comment: How can I populate adminId here? 
`adminInfo: {
    _id: false,
    adminId: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }]
  }`

Answer (score 7):

1. 

```js
lists: [{
    list: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        require: true,
        ref: "List"
    },
    allocations: [{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }]
}],
```

=> Because it's an array of objects, you can do this -: `Portfolio.populate('lists.list');`

2.

```js
lists: [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    require: true,
    ref: "List"
}]
```

=> Because it's an array, you just have to do this -: `Portfolio.populate('lists');`

Comment: XYZ.populate('adminInfo.adminId');

Comment: Already tried that please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62531177/how-to-populate-object-having-array-of-object-in-mongoose

Comment: The first one worked, but the second one didn't. Any idea why?

Answer (score 4):

if you have nested schema

```
YourSchema.find()
   .populate({
        path: 'map_data',
        populate: {
            path: 'location' 
        }
})
```

it's work for me

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Cart schema  
var CartSchema = new mongooseSchema({
    productDetails: [{
        productId: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: 'Product'

        },
        productCount: Number,
    }],
    UserId: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: true,
        trim: true,
    },
    shopId: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: true,
        trim: true,
    },
});

// add this .populate('productDetails.productId').

db.Cart.find({
    UserId: userId,
    shopId: shopId
}).populate('productDetails.productId')
.skip(pagination.skip)
.limit(pagination.limit)
.exec(function(error,

CartList) {

    if (error) {
        callback(error, null)
    } else {
        callback(null, CartList)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Populate didn't work in my case when nesting to array my Schema was

```js
const chatSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    chats: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "ChatMsg" 
    }],
})
```

How I solved it

```js
Chat.findOne({ 
    customer: req.body.customer, 
    agency: req.body.agency 
}, (err, chat) => {
    if (err) {
        res.status(422).send("Our fault");
    }

    chat.populate("chats").execPopulate(() => {
        res.send(chat);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
populate('lists.list')
populate(
 {
   path: "lists",
   populate : {
     path: "list",
     model: "List"
   }
 }
)
```

Comment: Please add more details explaining why your approach is working or better than previous answers.