# populating a key in an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, object, mongoose, populate

I am a new user to mongodb  and have a doubt regarding how to populate particular key of every object in an array .
here is the schema of the collection i want to populate

```
var Sub_cat = new mongoose.Schema({
    cat_id:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Cat"
    },
    name: String,
    quantity_type: String,
    selection_data:[{
        price:Number,
        selection_id:{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Selection"
        }
    }]
});
```

here i wish to populate selection_id in selection_data array which i wish to further populate.
can someone please help me out .
Thank you !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose populate with array of objects containing ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641210/mongoose-populate-with-array-of-objects-containing-ref)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able  populate like this:

```
Sub_cat.find({}).populate("selection_data.selection_id")
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Sub_cat.find({}).select('selection_data').populate({path:'selection_id', model:"Selection")
```