# How to populate object having array of object in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web, mongoose

I want to populate the `adminId` path to `User` Model.
Here is the code

```
adminInfo: {
    _id: false,
    adminId: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }]
 }
```

Here is a part of user schema:

```
// user schema
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      trim: true
    }
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true
  },
  phone: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    minlength: 10,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
    minlength: 6
  }
});
```

I have tried using `.populate('adminInfo.adminId')` but it's giving empty array [] whereas `.populate('adminInfo')` giving array of admins ids but not getting populated to User model

Comment: Hi! Please add the User schema to the question

Comment: Hi @Tunmee updated!

Comment: I thought the `adminInfo` property is a part of the User schema, from your latest edit, I can see it's not. Can you also share the schema where the `adminInfo` property exists

Comment: @Tunmee If `adminInfo` property will be a part of User schema then why I will refer that User schema??
`adminInfo` property is a part of `admin` schema from that I want to populate adminId to User schema

Comment: Can you also share the `admin` schema

Comment: @Tunmee it's pretty big, can you please tell me what you are looking for exactly?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think there is any problem with `.populate('adminInfo.adminId')` method.

are you sure that **ref** field is in **CamelCase** .

If not, try to change ref field ->

```
adminInfo: {
  _id: false,
  adminId: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user'
  }]
}
```

Comment: yes, I am sure, also it works when I am changing schena to : `adminId:[ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User' }]` and then `.populate('adminId')`