# Mongoose: populate an object inside an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate

I have a schema exported like that:

```
const PackageSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  maneuver: [
    {
      maneuverId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: ManeuverMainly,
      },
      period: { type: String, enum: ["day", "night"], required: true },
    },
  ],
  timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
});
```

When I make a  `find()` like that:

```
Package.find().populate("maneuver", "name").exec((err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ message: "Failed!" });
      return;
    }
    res.status(200).send(data);
});
```

My `populate` method does not work. **How can I populate my every `maneuverId` from `PackageSchema` with my `name` column from `ManeuverMainlySchema`?**

Obs: my `ManeuverMainlySchema` bellow:

```
const ManeuverMainlySchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date().now },
});
```

Comment: not tested, but have you tried `.populate("maneuver. maneuverId", "name")`?
taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641210/mongoose-populate-with-array-of-objects-containing-ref

Comment: ill add an answer then for future people to see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

taken from [Mongoose populate with array of objects containing ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641210/mongoose-populate-with-array-of-objects-containing-ref) you have to specify the field within the object of the array you want to populate against.

```
Package.find().populate("maneuver.maneuverId", "name").exec((err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ message: "Failed!" });
      return;
    }
    res.status(200).send(data);
});
```